# Vuetify 2.2, Why my footer is not aligned at absolute bottom on the Code Pen?

Tags: vuetify.js, footer, codepen

I have a [code pen](https://codepen.io/uedatakeyuki/pen/GRJmVmj) inside this code pen I have vuetify 2.2.15.

I've used footer as follow:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            Expected to align at bottom
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    <v-content>
    <v-footer>
      <v-col
        class="text-center"
      >
      footer
      </v-col>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

In the real code running on the web, this footer is aligned at the absolute bottom. But in the code pen, the footer is **NOT** aligned at the absolute bottom, but just follow the previous component relatively.

[image]

Is there any missing stack I should have used? Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use `absolute` in your `v-footer` like:

```
<v-footer absolute>
    <v-col class="text-center">
      footer
    </v-col>
</v-footer>
```

absolute prop applies `position: absolute` to the component.

also you should move `</v-content>` after your footer

your final code should be like:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-navigation-drawer app></v-navigation-drawer>
      <v-container>
        <v-card
        >
          <v-card-text
          >
            Expected to align at bottom
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    <v-footer absolute>
      <v-col
        class="text-center"
      >
      footer
      </v-col>
    </v-footer>
      </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```